# Running a spider (webcrawler) to find specific content

Tags: web-crawler

First of all I don't know whether this is the right place for this question. If not I'm sorry :)

Am thinking of writing a spider to crawl the web finding specific embedded files.

However I was wondering whether it is allowed by ISP's to run a spider, because it will make lots of request at a fast pace.

Or should I build in some delay in the requests?

I've read the contract of my ISP, but I couldn't find anything specific about crawling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) . It's got some helpful ideas. You should take note of the ROBOTS.txt on the site(s) you wish to crawl. And you should leave a delay between requests so as not to create denial-of-service conditions.

Comment: From the looks if it wget downloads the files for offline use. I just want to index it rather then downloading it. Are my findings correct?

Comment: @PeeHaa you don't say what "specific embedded files" are. If they are identified by their *content* you have to download them (I assume you can't run code on the server). You don't necessarily have to download the whole file - it depends how the server is configured. REST/HTTP allows part downloads

Comment: It doesn't matter what they are I just want to find and index them on the web.

Comment: what do you mean by "index"? if you can index them ONLY on filenames/URLs then do that. (I would expect that wget will allow that). But remember that if you rely on LINKS within the files to find the next files (which is what crawlers do) you will have to download the files. There is no magic. You cannot find links from files without reading the files. And I am not sure what your objection is. Worried about the volume? you shouldn't write a crawler. If you are worried about storing the files, don't. But for, say, HTML files you will have to read the files and find the <a href= .../> in them

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that could forbid you crawling. It not differs from normal user interaction. If you open page with lot of pictures, browser makes a lot of request at once.

You can have transfer limit - just note how much data you have downloaded.

The thing you must consider, is that crawling a lot of pages can be considered DoS attack or be forbidden by page operator. Follow their rules. If they require that no more than N request are done daily from one computer, respect it. Do some delays not to block access to site.